# Python changing to string from dict

Tags: python

I want to get data from something, I have the code but I want to change the way that I get data to string on one row.

**Code:**

```
def getBasicPlayers(self): # Finished
        """Returns a list containing a dictionary for each player:
        [
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
        ]
        Note: This will return an empty list if the player count is above 100."""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("c")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()
        reply = reply[11:] # Clean up bytes
        players = []

        strLen = struct.unpack("<h", reply[0:2])
        playerCount = strLen[0]

        reply = reply[2:] # Clean up bytes

        for i in range(playerCount):
            players.append({'name' : '', 'score' : 0})

        pointer = 0

        for player in players:
            strLen = ord(reply[pointer:(pointer + 1)])

            name = reply[(pointer + 1):(pointer + (strLen + 1))]

            temp = struct.unpack("<i", reply[(pointer + (strLen + 1)):(pointer + (strLen + 5))])
            pointer += (strLen + 5)

            player['name'] = name
            player['score'] = temp[0]

        return players
```

I receive information, but I don't get it how I want. Now it's like:

> Player1 (1)
>
> Player2 (15)
>
> Player3 (20)

I want to make it like:

> Player1 (1), Player2 (15), Player3(20)

The file that actually returns informations:

```
query.connect() 
    basicPlayers = query.getBasicPlayers() 

    if basicPlayers: # If the server has players online
        for player in basicPlayers:
            return str(player['name'])+" "+str(player['score'])
    else:
        return "No players"
```

Can someone transform the code if possible, please? Any help will be appreciated!

Edit:

That's the whole query file, since I noticed it won't work if I post only getBasicPlayers():

```
import socket
import struct

class SampQuery:

    def __init__(self, sock=None, server="127.0.0.1", port=7777):
        if sock is None:
            self.serverVars = [server, port]
        else:
            self.sock = sock


    def connect(self):
        try:
            self.serverVars[0] = socket.gethostbyname(self.serverVars[0])
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
            self.sock = socket.socket(
                socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # Internet and UDP
        except socket.gaierror:
            return False

        packet = self.assemblePacket("p0101")

        try:
            self.send(packet)

            reply = self.receive()[10:]

            if reply == 'p0101':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except socket.timeout:
            return False


    def send(self, msg):
            self.sock.sendto(msg, (self.serverVars[0], self.serverVars[1]))


    def receive(self, buffer=1024):
        msg = self.sock.recv(buffer)
        return msg


    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()


    def getInfo(self): # Finished
        """Returns a dictionary containing server information:
        {
            'password' : integer,
            'players' : integer,
            'maxplayers' : integer,
            'hostname' : string,
            'gamemode' : string,
            'mapname' : string,
        }"""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("i")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()

        reply = reply[11:]

        serverInfo = {'password' : 0, 'players' : 0, 'maxplayers' : 0, 'hostname' : "", 'gamemode' : "", 'mapname' : ""}

        serverInfo['password'] = ord(reply[0:1])

        players = struct.unpack("<h", reply[1:3])

        serverInfo['players'] = players[0];

        maxPlayers = players = struct.unpack("<h", reply[3:5])

        serverInfo['maxplayers'] = maxPlayers[0];

        reply = reply[5:] # Clean up bytes

        strLen = struct.unpack("<i", reply[0:4])

        serverInfo['hostname'] = reply[4:(strLen[0]+4)]

        reply = reply[(strLen[0]+4):] # Clean up bytes

        strLen = struct.unpack("<i", reply[0:4])

        serverInfo['gamemode'] = reply[4:(strLen[0]+4)]

        reply = reply[(strLen[0]+4):] # Clean up bytes

        strLen = struct.unpack("<i", reply[0:4])

        serverInfo['map'] = reply[4:(strLen[0]+4)]

        return serverInfo


    def getBasicPlayers(self): # Finished
        """Returns a list containing a dictionary for each player:
        [
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
            {
                'name' : string,
                'score' : integer,
            },
        ]
        Note: This will return an empty list if the player count is above 100."""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("c")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()
        reply = reply[11:] # Clean up bytes
        players = []

        strLen = struct.unpack("<h", reply[0:2])
        playerCount = strLen[0]

        reply = reply[2:] # Clean up bytes

        for i in range(playerCount):
            players.append({'name' : '', 'score' : 0})

        pointer = 0

        for player in players:
            strLen = ord(reply[pointer:(pointer + 1)])

            name = reply[(pointer + 1):(pointer + (strLen + 1))]

            temp = struct.unpack("<i", reply[(pointer + (strLen + 1)):(pointer + (strLen + 5))])
            pointer += (strLen + 5)

            player['name'] = name
            player['score'] = temp[0]

        return players


    def getDetailedPlayers(self): # Finished
        """Returns a list containing a dictionary for each player:
            [
                {
                    'id' : integer,
                    'name' : string,
                    'score' : integer,
                    'ping' : integer,
                },
                {
                    'id' : integer,
                    'name' : string,
                    'score' : integer,
                    'ping' : integer,
                },
            ]
            Note: This will return an empty list if the player count is above 100."""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("d")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()
        reply = reply[11:] # Clean up bytes
        players = []

        strLen = struct.unpack("<h", reply[0:2])
        playerCount = strLen[0]

        reply = reply[2:] # Clean up bytes

        for i in range(playerCount):
            players.append({'id' : 0, 'name' : '', 'score' : 0, 'ping' : 0})

        pointer = 0

        for player in players:
            id = ord(reply[pointer:(pointer + 1)])

            strLen = ord(reply[(pointer + 1):(pointer + 2)])

            name = reply[(pointer + 2):(pointer + (strLen + 2))]

            score = struct.unpack("<i", reply[(pointer + (strLen + 2)):(pointer + (strLen + 6))])

            ping = struct.unpack("<i", reply[(pointer + (strLen + 6)):(pointer + (strLen + 10))])

            pointer += (strLen + 10)

            player['id'] = id
            player['name'] = name
            player['score'] = score[0]
            player['ping'] = ping[0]

        return players


    def getRules(self): # Finished
        """Returns a list containing a dictionary for each rule:
        [
            {
                'rule' : string,
                'value' : integer,
            },
            {
                'rule' : string,
                'value' : integer,
            },
        ]"""
        packet = self.assemblePacket("r")
        self.send(packet)

        reply = self.receive()
        reply = reply[11:] # Clean up bytes
        rules = []

        strLen = struct.unpack("<h", reply[0:2])
        ruleCount = strLen[0]

        reply = reply[2:] # Clean up bytes

        for i in range(ruleCount):
            rules.append({'rule' : '', 'value' : ''})

        pointer = 0

        for rule in rules:
            strLen = ord(reply[pointer:(pointer + 1)])

            name = reply[(pointer + 1):(pointer + (strLen + 1))]

            strLenVal = ord(reply[(pointer + (strLen + 1)):(pointer + (strLen + 2))])

            value = reply[(pointer + (strLen + 2)):(pointer + ((strLen + strLenVal) + 2))]

            pointer += ((strLen + strLenVal) + 2)

            rule['rule'] = name
            rule['value'] = value

        return rules


    def assemblePacket(self, type):
        ipSplit = str.split(self.serverVars[0], '.')

        packet = 'SAMP'
        packet += chr(int(ipSplit[0]))
        packet += chr(int(ipSplit[1]))
        packet += chr(int(ipSplit[2]))
        packet += chr(int(ipSplit[3]))
        packet += chr(self.serverVars[1] & 0xFF)
        packet += chr(self.serverVars[1] >> 8 & 0xFF)
        packet += type

        return packet
```

Edit2:

```
query.connect() # If the program has made a successful connection to the server
    basicPlayers = query.getBasicPlayers() # Returns False if no players are online
    if basicPlayers:
        return ", ".join(("{0} {1}".format(basicPlayers['name'], basicPlayers['score'])))
```

Comment: Do you have incorrect indentation in the last bit there?

Comment: Lol no, the code works but I don't like the way its displayed.

Comment: `query.connect()` has a different indentation level than `basicPlayers = query.getBasicPlayers()`. If that code works as written, I will be *very* surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what code this is or how it works like you say it does:

```
for player in basicPlayers:
    return #anything
```

When you return, it should stop execution of that function. If you were using `yield`, I would expect to see that output, depending on how you're calling the function.

However, you can easily change that part to join on a generator expression. I've also included string formatting:

```
if basicPlayers:
    return ", ".join(("{0} {1}".format(player['name'], player['score'])))
```

Which should do what you're after.

Comment: Ok, I posted the whole code of the file that gets info. This one gives me invalid syntax error.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2,6. I think I have to try 2,7 as well, might be that.

Comment: Yeah, tried it on Python 2,7, but yet the same error:      return ", ".join(("{0} {1}".format(player['name'], player['score']))
                                                                        ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Ah, it's missing a parenthesis. Try that.

Comment: query.connect() # If the program has made a successful connection to the server
 basicPlayers = query.getBasicPlayers() # Returns False if no players are online
 if basicPlayers:
  return ", ".join(("{0} {1}".format(basicPlayers['name'], basicPlayers['score'])))

Again: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Are you replacing `return str(player['name'])+" "+str(player['score'])` and its preceding if statement? You should update your original post with the code snippet and exception - commenting removes most formatting. And there is no way that your original code worked, if you've replaced it with my code and are still getting the same error.

Comment: Wayne, done. I updated it.

Comment: Your code worked the way it was written before?

Comment: No it didn't, it gave me that string / dict error, and it gives me it again wow.